# "Error in deserializing body of request message for operation" happen when I use Ksoap2 to call WCF

Tags: android, wcf, wsdl

I wanted to use KSoap2 to Call WCF. But some error happened.
I don't know if I need to setting other attributes of OperationContract ?

would anyone can help me?

I will appreciate you very much

this is my WCF OperationContract

```
[OperationContract (Name = "HelloWorld")]
string HelloWorld(string username);
```

here is my WSDL

```
<wsdl:operation name="ComparePassWord">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IITRIService/ComparePassWord"   style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

here are my Java Code

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "HelloWorld");
PropertyInfo HelloWorld = new PropertyInfo();
HelloWorld.setType(String.class);
HelloWorld.setName("username");
HelloWorld.setValue(username);
request.addProperty(HelloWorld);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
// Set output SOAP object
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
// Create HTTP call object
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
try {
  // Invoke web service
     androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_URL,envelope);
    }  catch (Exception e) {
            //Print error
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Assign error message to resTxt
            resTxt = "Error occured";
        }
        SoapObject response = null;

        try {
            // Get the response

            response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
            //Print error
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Assign error message to resTxt

            return new String[]{"fail"};
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by update my WCF to  version 4.5.

WCF will show just the operations in the WSDL itself - the data structures are documented in XSD files that are linked to the WSDL file.

When I update my WCF to Version. I can got entire WSDL including all XSD elements